# Generate a URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement of getting two values from two drop downs and by those values i need to generate a URL.
In below code it posts certain data in json format into the options tag, when **getid** is clicked based on get id it retrieves data from a another link into a options tag. both options tag values are combined and a URL is generated which is `http://localhost:8080/pmatool/RiskServlet?project='+e+'&sprint='+f`

```js
var e;
$('#getid').on('click', function(){
    e=document.getElementById('proid').value;

    $.ajax({
      type : 'GET',
      dataType: "json",
      url: 'http://localhost/redmine/projects/'+e+'/issue_categories.json',
      
      success: function(results){
            
            

            $.each(results.issue_categories, function(i,value) {
              $('.issuecatclss').append('<option value="' + value.name + '">'+ value.name + '<option>'
                
                ); 
            });
           

        }
    });
});

$('#getsprint').on('click', function(){
    var f=document.getElementById('issucatid').value;
 
    });

$.ajax({
      type : 'GET',
      dataType: "json",
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/pmatool/RiskServlet?project='+e+'&sprint='+f,

      success: function(results){
                  
            $(results.assigns).each( function(i, value){
        $('.risktable').append('<tr>' +
                                '<td>'+ (i+1) +'</td>'+ 
                                '<td>'+ value.assigned_to +'</td>'+ 
                                '<td>'+value.status+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+value.tasks.length+'</td>'+
                            '</tr>');
        });

   
        }
    });
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label>Project ID  &nbsp;</label>
    <select class="form-control proidclss" id="proid"></select> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
<button  class="btn btn-default" id="getid" style="margin-top: 25px;">Get ID</button></div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label>Issue Catogory  &nbsp;</label>
    <select class="form-control issuecatclss" id="issucatid"></select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
    <button  class="btn btn-default" id="getsprint" style="margin-top: 25px;">Get Sprint</button></div>
</div>
```

Generation of this link `http://localhost:8080/pmatool/RiskServlet?project='+e+'&sprint='+f` doesn't work now. Please have a look and tell me why, final URL is not generate.

Comment: The variable `f` is scoped to that small function in the click handler. Anywhere else it will be undefined.

Comment: I came up with the same assessment as Xufox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax call should be inside click event like this:

```
$('#getsprint').on('click', function(){
    var f=document.getElementById('issucatid').value;
    var e=document.getElementById('proid').value;
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/pmatool/RiskServlet?project='+e+'&sprint='+f,

        success: function(results){

            $(results.assigns).each( function(i, value){
            $('.risktable').append('<tr>' +
                                    '<td>'+ (i+1) +'</td>'+ 
                                    '<td>'+ value.assigned_to +'</td>'+ 
                                    '<td>'+value.status+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+value.tasks.length+'</td>'+
                                '</tr>');
            });


        }
    });
});
```